# PostgreSQL db volume at 100%. Can I create a tablespace on another volume so I can vacuum full?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have run out of space, because I am new to Postgres and I have just not been monitoring it properly.

Now I cannot even vacuum the tables:

```
ERROR:  could not extend file "base/20851/11787": No space left on device
```

I have deleted a whole bunch of data. I realize that only `vacuum full` will bring back space though.

I have another logical volume with lots of space on it. Can I create some kind of a tablespace over there? If so, is there a specific kind of space to tell the database to do it's "work" over there during the vacuum process? Or do I need to physically move tables to that tablespace? How do I do that?

I apologize for the rapid fire questions. I have found myself in a bit of a spot.

This is PostgreSQL 9.3.

Comment: Depends on just how full it is. You need space to write WAL records in order to create a tablespace. There are some nasty catch-22 situations around out-of-disk-space issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what You can do to move your data to the new tablespace :

1. Create the new tablespace pointing to the new location.

   ```
   postgres=# create TABLESPACE movespace LOCATION '/home/postgres_tbsp';
   CREATE TABLESPACE
   ```
2. Alter table or database to move to the new tablespace.

   ```
   postgres=# ALTER DATABASE slonmaster SET tablespace movespace;
   ALTER DATABASE
   ```

This process could last long as it moves all the data in the table or database to a new location.

Comment: ... which will probably run out of disk space due to the need to write WAL for the table move.

Comment: I freed up about 3GB by moving older WAL files. That at least let me set the temp_tablespace over to the new tablespace. Now I'm "vacuum full"-ing smaller to successively larger tables to give me the space I need.

Comment: From the behavior I'm seeing, it looks like "vacuum full" rebuilds the file on disk in a tmp directory, then rewrites the whole table to a new file and deletes the old file.

Comment: @AKWF , yes, the vacuum full rebuild the table You're vacuuming, so it needs free space as big as the table you're vacuuming